# Plotting Outline with PyQt5 extremely slow

Tags: python, pyqt5, spyder

Okay, so I recently upgraded Spyder to version 4.1.4 and ever since I have the issue that all plots are extremely slow in showing. I am plotting Outline with Qt5 (v. 5.9.2). I already tried downgrading spyder back to 4.1.3 as well as 4.1.2 but neither helped.

So when I plot some simple data the plot in the extra window takes a few seconds to actually show the data and when I want to switch between one plot or the other it takes 5-10 seconds to show me the other plot.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? I could not find anything online so far. Any suggestions are welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

I am experiencing the same thing. All my Qt5 applications became extremely slow after upgrading to Spyder 4.1.4, did not find a solution yet, unfortunately.

/e Rolling back my entire Conda environment did 'solve' it for me though.

Comment: Ohh I did not know that anaconda had revisions, I will try that :D anyone looking for how to do it, take a look here: https://www.shriramjaju.page/2018-05-30-2-minute-recipe-how-to-rollback-your-conda-environment/

Comment: It was a life saver for me, I hope it did the trick for you as well. I'm still interested to hear when someone manages to locate which package specifically is causing the issues (apparently not spyder itself, judging from your comment on rolling back spyder being not effective).

Comment: Unfortunately I could not do a rollback, so I will have to reinstall and just upgrade to spyder 4.1.3. In case anyone finds a solution/the causing library I will update to 4.1.4

Comment: @Nix by "just" uninstalling anaconda and installing the newest version it was fixed for me. That is quite an awful solution but since my environment crashed it was my only option anyways.